# Chevy S-10 no brakes

Tags: brakes, abs

I have a Chevy S-10 with 270,000 miles, RWD, ABS. 
One of the brake lines burst, and I replaced all of the lines. I used a pressure bleeder, and did an ABS bleed with the scan tool. I get a hard pedal with the key off, but with the engine running, the pedal goes to the floor. There’s no external leaks and I tested the master cylinder. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: If it's definately not the master cylinder, then try a very thorough bleed on all 4 corners. When I have doubts about getting all the air out I always use the two person manual bleed method. Many times the ABS bleeding needs to be done multiple times.

Comment: And if that fails, get a vacuum bleeder setup. One of those will route out bubbles like nobody's business.

Comment: Power boosters can be very deceptive. They can give so much assist that the pedal seems to go to the floor. Meaning that the pedal seems to go to the floor but the breaks would have locked up long ago. Have you tried driving the truck around to see how the breaks perform?